# Why won't .filter() work in Interent Explorer 7 till 11?

Tags: javascript

My question is:

```
var data  = db.filter(function (el) {
    return (el.TBL === TBL && el.P == PID);
});
```

This is the error I am getting.

> Object doesn't support this property or method

I am not understanding the error and looking help to resolve this.

Comment: iE 7 till 11 doesent support this line kindly help me out this

Comment: I think it is supported from IE9 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: what id `db` is it an array?

Comment: If it is an array... then you can use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill)

Comment: yes this is an array like this

Comment: var db = [
{ "TBL": "ABCD", "P": 0, "I": 001, "T": "Alpha" },
{ "TBL": "ABCD", "P": 0, "I": 002, "T": "Bravo" },
{ "TBL": "ABCD", "P": 0, "I": 003, "T": "Charlie" },
{ "TBL": "ABCD", "P": 0, "I": 004, "T": "Delta" },
];

Comment: So it is an array... so just add the above polyfill to add support for .filter()

Comment: How to add polyfill??? i have no idea about polyfill??

Comment: Just add the code given in the [polyfill section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) to your script file... add it at the top of your script file

Comment: again Error 


0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'TBL' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.filter is not supported until IE9 according to the MDN. You could try using this instead:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = db.length; i--;) {
        var el = db[i];
        if (el.TBL !== TBL || el.P !== PID) {
                db.splice(i, 1);
        }
}
```

Edit: ok, I see what your problem is. Take a look at one of the objects in `db`:

```
 { "TBL": "ABCD", "P": 0, "I": 001, "T": "Alpha" }
```

The value for I should be a string, not a number. Try writing it like this:

```
 { TBL: "ABCD", P: 0, I: "001", T: "Alpha" }
```

This works when I test it out in REPL.

Comment: this could be an error

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'TBL' of undefined or null reference

Comment: this rise an error

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'TBL' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @kpimov looks like it's an array of objects. Check OP's comments in his question

Comment: @kpimov 


JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'TBL' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I have got error in TBL

Comment: i have add Polyfil i still not get any help